# how to add full screen welcome image on a web app using jquerymobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I think it's there in jQTouch but how do I add a full screen welcome image for my iPhone web app developed using jQueryMobile?

The app is a full screen web app and it is already added in the iPhone Homescreen.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is just a concept but you could try something like this:

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/yzvWy/14/

JS

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(hideSplash, 2000);
});

function hideSplash() {
  $.mobile.changePage("#home", "fade");
}
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="splash" style="background-color: #fff;"> 
    <div class="splash">
        <img src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/_assets/images/jquery-logo.png" alt="splash" />
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="content"> 
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b"> 
                <li data-role="list-divider">Overview</li> 
                <li><a href="docs/about/intro.html">Intro to jQuery Mobile</a></li> 
                <li><a href="docs/about/features.html">Features</a></li> 
                <li><a href="docs/about/accessibility.html">Accessibility</a></li> 
                <li><a href="docs/about/platforms.html">Supported platforms</a></li> 
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

iOS has its propertiary stuff for displaying a splash while app loads. I didn't use it yet (I didn't need that) but here's how they say it can be done:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="img/splash.png" />
```

You might want this too:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./apple-touch-icon.png" />
```

See here for more:
http://matt.might.net/articles/how-to-native-iphone-ipad-apps-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. This didn't work with the current stable release of Jquery Mobile, since it doesn't yet support 1.7. I managed to combine it another solution on the matter and came up with:

```
$ (function(){
setTimeout(function(){
    $.mobile.changePage("#home", "fade");
}, 3000);
});
```

Thanks!