# jQuery Mobile background image not showing on a full screen iPad web app

Tags: web-applications, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

I have set a background on the data-role="page" element like so

```
<div data-role="page" style="background: transparent url('img/background.jpg') no-repeat;" >
```

It works perfectly fine on a desktop browser and on the iPad safari browser.

The issue I am having is that when you add the website to the home screen as an 'app' and it is a full screen web app. It doesn't show the background...

I have tried setting it via a style sheet and inline and both ways give me the same issue.

I am completely out of ideas as to why this wouldn't work.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: How big is the background.jpg image? Does Mobile Safari debug say anything?

Comment: Mobile Safari debug isn't reporting any errors and the background shows in the Safari browsing app just not in full screen. The background image is 1024x768px

Comment: add this to your CSS: html, body {
   background: #ccc url(../images/background.jpg);
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 100%;
   }

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332989/how-to-add-full-screen-welcome-image-on-a-web-app-using-jquerymobile

Comment: I'm not trying to add a welcome page. I just want to set a background to the whole app. Not related.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end this is what worked for me.

```
<div data-role="page" id="home" style="background: #000000 
    url('img/background.jpg') repeat;">
```

wouldn't work via a css file.

Answer (score 2):

Apply this to the element:

```
.#target-element {
    background : transparent url(YOUR_URL) 0 0 no-repeat fixed !important;
    background-size : cover;
}​
```

Comment: It works... I just needed to set div height and done. If you need to center image in the background, change 0 0 by 50% 50%

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-page 
{

    background-image: url("img1.jpg");
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS file:

```
[data-role=page] {
    background: transparent url('img/background.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a css class and end every attribute with `!important` to over-rule framework css. Thats why it is working inline only