# Different background images jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to set different background images for each page in jquery mobile.

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">...
    </div>

<div data-role="page" id="pagetwo">...
    </div>
```

As you can see, each page has a different id, so my thought was that i can assign background image for that id (and another image for another id)

```
#pageone {background: transparent url(URL) repeat center center !important;}
#pagetwo {background: transparent url(URL) repeat center center !important;}
```

The image is a pattern (really small 7x10 px). But i couldn't do it. For some reason it appears when you load the page (outside the page div) but then it disappears.

Did anyone encounter the same problem and knows what can i do about it?

Ty in advance :)

Comment: Try removing transparent from your styles. Also try placing them inline if previous trick doesn't work. You can refer this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741733/jquery-mobile-background-image-not-showing-on-a-full-screen-ipad-web-app

Comment: Didn't work (i've check the link too). If i put another div inside page i can style him but that isn't the background for the whole page. If possible i would like to know how to style the "page" div.

Comment: I created a fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/189/ . Added the dimensions to the div.

Comment: I see now, thank you. Is it possible without setting specific height?

Comment: I think you need to set height in order to use this pattern as background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using theme roller and importing my theme there.
Then duplicated it into swatch b c and d.
In my CSS file i changed the color to background image (for each swatch there was a different image)
In my html i put:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageone" class="ui-page-theme-a">...
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="pageone" class="ui-page-theme-b">...
    </div>
```

and that for each page i have that have their own background image.